# SQL esconder parâmetro de consulta no retorno

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT idProdutos, SUM(quantidade) as soma
FROM pedidos
GROUP BY idProdutos
ORDER BY soma DESC
```

Que me retorna o *id* e a somatória agrupada dos produtos na tabela.

Porém, preciso que me retorne apenas o `idProdutos` para eu colocar em uma cláusula IN conforme abaixo.

Isso é meio que esconder parâmetro de consulta `soma` no retorno.

Será que existe uma forma de fazer isso no `MySQL`?

```
$string = "SELECT 
            idProdutos, 
            idCategorias,  
            codigo,   
            nome,    
            data,  
            precoUnitario,  
            bloqueado,  
            lancamento,   
            freteGratis,
            oportunidade,
            descricao,  
            desconto,
            estoque,    
            peso
            FROM produtos
            WHERE idProdutos IN 
            (
                SELECT idProdutos, SUM(quantidade) as soma
                FROM pedidos
                GROUP BY idProdutos
                ORDER BY soma DESC                          
            )
            LIMIT 0,12";
```

Comment: é só tirar o `, SUM(quantidade) as soma` e o `ORDER BY soma DESC` que funciona, não entendi o porque de vc precisar deles nesse caso

Comment: Bom, você entendeu essa consulta? Ela pesquisa a soma das quantidades dos produtos na tabela de pedidos e ordena dos mais vendidos para os menos vendidos. Mas eu só preciso dos idProdutos a siada dessa consulta para usar em uma clausula IN de outra query que só aceita os idPodutos

Comment: Não funciona fazer `order by sum(quantidade) desc`?

Comment: @CarlosRocha essa query não faz isso, vou refazer ela do jeito que vc quer

Comment: @CarlosRocha o resultado dessa query não é o que vc espera, para funcionar o `limit` tinha que ser na query de dentro e não na de fora

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, é isso mesmo, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Jeferson,

Você pode substitir por esse código, qual irá retornar todos os produtos vendidos:

```
....WHERE idProdutos IN(SELECT distinct(idProdutos)FROM pedidos)
```

Agora se precisa dos produtos mais vendidos, o correto seria utilizar rank que no caso tem no Oracle, mas fazendo dessa forma creio que funcione:

```
SELECT prod.idProdutos,
   prod.idCategorias,
   prod.codigo,
   prod.nome,
   prod.data,
   prod.precoUnitario,
   prod.bloqueado,
   prod.lancamento,
   prod.freteGratis,
   prod.oportunidade,
   prod.descricao,
   prod.desconto,
   prod.estoque,
   prod.peso,
 --  ped.soma -- caso queira mostrar a quantidade remova o comentário
FROM produtos as prod, 
(SELECT idProdutos, SUM(quantidade) as soma
    FROM pedidos
    GROUP BY idProdutos
    ORDER BY soma DESC
) ped 
WHERE prod.idProdutos = ped.idProdutos
LIMIT 0,12
order by ped.soma
```

Answer (score 0):

Um a boa maneira de se fazer isso é usando um `JOIN` com a tabela que você quer e agrupar tudo da primeira tabela. Poderia fazer da sua maneira também porém o `LIMIT` teria que está na SubQuery e não na Query principal

```
SELECT 
   p.idProdutos, 
   p.idCategorias,  
   p.codigo,   
   p.nome,    
   p.data,  
   p.precoUnitario,  
   p.bloqueado,  
   p.lancamento,   
   p.freteGratis,
   p.oportunidade,
   p.descricao,  
   p.desconto,
   p.estoque, 
   p.peso
FROM produtos p
  JOIN pedidos pe
    ON p.idProdutos = pe.idProdutos
GROUP BY p.idProdutos, p.idCategorias, p.codigo, p.nome, p.data, p.precoUnitario, p.bloqueado, p.lancamento, 
   p.freteGratis, p.oportunidade, p.descricao, p.desconto, p.estoque, p.peso
ORDER BY SUM(pe.quantidade) DESC 
LIMIT 0,12
```

Comment: assim não dá pois estou usando orientação a objetos e na classe produtos não tem um atributo soma. Mas Valeu, ordenando pela soma também deu certo

Comment: @CarlosRocha é só tirar o atributo da consulta, vou ajustar a query, só testar agora

Answer (score -1):

Grato a quem ajudou.

Mas achei que assim ficou mais simples:

```
            SELECT 
              idProdutos, 
               idCategorias,  
               codigo,   
               nome,    
               data,  
               precoUnitario,  
               bloqueado,  
               lancamento,   
               freteGratis,
               oportunidade,
               descricao,  
               desconto,
               estoque, 
               peso
            FROM produtos
            WHERE idProdutos IN (
                SELECT idProdutos
                FROM pedidos
                GROUP BY idProdutos
                ORDER BY sum(quantidade) desc                       
            )
            LIMIT 0,12
```

Comment: Acredito que desas maneira n irá funcionar como vc quer, o `LIMIT` tem que está na sua SubQuery e não na Query principal

Comment: MySQL não aceita LIMIT na subquery. E, imagine que o retorno sejam 5 id's ordenados pelas maiores quantidades, por exemplo, todos os retornos seriam, os ids 25, 4, 7, 12. 15,49, etc... Se o limite da query principal for por exemplo LIMIT 0,3, logo, sairão apenas os retornos de 25, 4 e 7

Comment: tente isso http://stackoverflow.com/a/7124492/4166090

Comment: ... WHERE idProdutos IN (
                SELECT distinct idProdutos
                FROM pedidos)